# node.js & express - Send Response From Back End To Front End

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express

I'm new to working with express/node.js and I was just wondering how I could send the response I get from node to the front end (I'm using Angular in the front end).

Node.js basically reads a directory and logs all the files in it, here is the code:

**Server**

```
 router.get('/files/:id/', function(req, res)
{
   let fileUrl = path.join(SERVER, 'files', sanitizeFileName(req.params.id));

   fs.readdir(fileUrl, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file);
      res.send(file);
    });
  })
});
```

Now I need to display the file names in the front end, kinda like this:

**Front end**

```
<div class="files">
        <p>Files in {{ id }} directory:</p>
        <p>>{{ file }}</p>   
    </div>
```

I tried it with this method in the front end but I'm getting an empty object for some reason

```
this.file = this.http.request(this.server).map( (file:any) => { JSON.parse(file) } );
```

Comment: What type of object is files: array of objects? What is the schema?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create service in Angular project and fetch the url's(example- http://localhost:3000/api/users) after testing API by Postman

Comment: I already have the URL and I read the filename from the backend.
Why do I need to create a service to send the filename as a string to the front end?

Comment: By Expressjs and nodejs you just created an API , now if you want to create angular project then it must include a service which has all its get, post,put,delete method and use these method objects into your components to create UI

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.readdir(fileUrl, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file);
      res.send(file);
    });
  })
```

you can't response multiple times for a request. This could be done only once.

Better you try to push file names in a array and send it to front end and populate it there.

Change it to

```
fs.readdir(fileUrl, (err, files) => {
        var filenames = [];
        files.forEach(file => {
          filenames.push(file);
        });
        res.status(200).send(filenames);
      })
```

Comment: if you are using type script then you probably need to add 
var filenames:string[];

Comment: it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in the server log

Answer (score 0):

As krishnashu pointed out, it is not possible to send multiple responses with res.send (though it is possible to chain responses with res.write and res.end).

I suggest that you send the whole array of files at once instead of traversing the array with foreach. There is no need to do this as long as you don't want to modify the files at this stage.

You can simply turn the array into a JSON-style string and return it to the client application: 
`res.json(JSON.stringify(files))`

Comment: Thank you! And how exactly do I fetch them in the front end? Will it do that automatically?